# How to write CSV to JSON without a header row, using CDL

Tags: java, json, csv

I had some data the mongodb database in JSON format...I wanto to convert it into JSON format for further processing....I converted my data into CSV format but I don't want the headings in the CSV file....I  Want to remove the headings from the CSV file. Hope my question is clear now.........

My CSV file has the following format.

```
 **date,lng,time,place**

 16-05-2013,77.152515,NIGHT,LosAngeles
 16-05-2013,,77.883754,EVENING,NY
 -----------------------------------
 ------------------------------------
 -------------------------------------
```

I converted my jsondata into CSV and tried to replace the headings **date,lng,time,place** but I didn't find any way to do it through coding.....Can anyone guide me....

```
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(data.getJsonData());
    JSONArray docs =  root.getJSONArray("data");
    File file=new File("/home/Documents/file1.csv");
    String csv = CDL.toString(docs);

    System.out.println("csv"+csv);
    try {
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file,csv);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How are you *writing* to the CSV file? Does the string `csv` in your code contain the contents of the CSV file?

Comment: @toddlermenot i have editted my question.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the `toString` that takes a separate array of names, passing the names like so:

```
String csv = CDL.toString(docs.getJSONObject(0).names(), docs);
```

If you want to avoid a `JSONException` on an empty `docs` array you will want to check to make sure that `docs` is not empty before doing the above.

For more details, take a look at the documentation for[`CDL`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/CDL.html#toString(org.json.JSONArray,%20org.json.JSONArray)), in particular `CDL.toString(JSONArray, JSONArray)`, which states:

> The list of names is not included in the output.

If you take a look at [the source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/json/CDL.java.html) you can get a slightly clearer idea of what is happening.

Note that if you want to change the set of columns in the output, or their order, you can pass in any `JSONArray` of names you want as the first parameter - the output columns will correspond to the names in that array.